# Fix Broken DNF Dependencies on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

Whenever I try to use DNF to update my system, I always have a collection of packages with broken dependencies.

[image: DNF - Skipping packages with broken dependencies]

Since upgrading to Fedora 22, I've been receiving this listing of broken packages, but I never did anything about them, but now that I want to upgrade to Fedora 23, they seem to be causing issues that are preventing me from completing an upgrade.

How can I fix these packages so that the dependencies are not broken? I cannot find anything online that is particularly helpful related to the issue, and I never became comfortable with DNF since Fedora makes it easy to use with old `yum` commands.

I was able to get more detailed error messages by using `sudo yum update --best --allowerasing`, although I am unsure of what they mean.

[image: More Detailed Error Messages]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not DNF's fault, but yours. The problem is that you have enabled EPEL repositories in Fedora. I don't know why you did that, but I'm quite sure the problems will disappear when you disable them.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very well-versed in the use of Fedora repositories, so it's quite possible that I would do something like that.

Comment: I think that you should remove the packages installed from EPEL, then disable that repos and reinstall them from Fedora repos. Here is some info about EPEL: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what the root of the problem is, use "dnf -b" as discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341334/101059.